# Why is Backpropogation used instead of Rosenblatt's learning Algo or gradient descent to train MLP's?

Tags: gradient-descent, supervised-learning, backpropagation

In roesnblatt's learning algo and gradient descent the output is calculated for each input and based on the error b/w the outputs calculated and desired outputs the weights are updated. Why is backpropogation preferred over these methods which are so much simpler?